# Angular ng-model can't get value

Tags: angularjs

can you help to get the ng-model data

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model = "DateSchedule" required>
<button type="submit" ng-click="saveReservation()" class="btn btn-primary pull-right"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Schedule</button>
```

in the script i already place the controller and app

```
alert($scope.DateSchedule);
```

it return me undefined

thanks

Comment: Where do you have the alert? Inside the saveReservation() method? We might need a bit more code to show us where/how. Also, how about the ng-app/ng-controller, it may be that they're in the wrong place. Is everything else in the code working as you'd expect?

Comment: Is the above HTML by chance inside an `ngIf`?

Comment: Share your complete code, also try to make live demo in code snippet, use `<>` symbol after edit

Comment: i place the ng app and controller above
<div class="container"  ng-app="dashboardApp" ng-controller="dashboardCtrl">
</div>